# Grounding subpanel to box - 'tap threads'

Tags: electrical, grounding, subpanel

I've installed a subpanel and need to ground the grounding bar to the actual panel box.  I was instructed to run a #6 jumper to a hole on the box, attach with a screw, making sure to 'tap threads'.  Unfamiliar with the term 'tap threads', what do I need to know?

Comment: Aren't subpanels *not* to be bonded?

Comment: I can't answer this question with any sort of expertise, but during final inspection the inspector indicated this needed to be done.  After googling around, I did find this:  [House Wiring](http://books.google.com/books?id=wekKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA290#v=onepage&q&f=false), which supports that direction.

Comment: Disregard, I was thinking of the neutral.

Comment: Sounds a bit wrong IMHO. A ground bar should come with screws to mount *it* straight to the panel with shipped screws appropriately sized and colored for this application. Secondly, tell Mr. Inspector to come up with better advice - #6 wrapped on a screw; are you kidding me; how big of a screw did he tell you to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*tap threads*", likely means to use a [tap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_and_die#Tap) to make threads in the hole.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the tap straight up and down. When (or before) it gets hard to turn, back it out to clear the chips. On all but cast iron, use oil as a lubricant.

I'd use a [lug](http://www.onlinecomponents.com/panduit-lama614qy.html?p=12198429&ref=Nextag.com) instead of wrapping it around a screw.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I like the idea of a lug--I'll likely go this route.